# Can one avoid "WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost" after sleeping

Tags: tensorflow.js

If I'm training in TFJS and need to put my laptop to sleep the training is halted when I wake up the laptop.  The console says:

```
WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost
```

followed by an exception.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The training is halted because of an increase in the memory used by webgl. There might be a memory leak in the code.

What to do ?

- check the memory footprints using tf.memory()
- clean up all unused tensors

Comment: But I don't lose the WebGL context if I let it run to completion. So sleep is needed to trigger this. But I did just try a very simple training example and sleep resume didn't cause a problem. This might be limited to Chrome on Windows 10.